# «Молодой человек» — применимо только к мужчинам?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания, род, обращение

Почему словосочетание "молодой человек" применимо только к мужчинам?
Возможно, имеется какая-то история происхождения?

Comment: Ну хотя бы потому, что "человек" - грамматически мужского рода.   "Молодая человек" невозможно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из толкового словаря Дмитриева:
[челове́к](http://endic.ru/dmytriev/Chelovek-5238.html)
*сущ., **м.**, употр. наиб. часто*
**15.** Когда женщина или пожилой мужчина вежливо обращаются к незнакомому юноше или молодому мужчине, то они называют его **молодым человеком.**

В словаре семнадцать позиций, описывающих значение-употребление слова "человек". Все они (за исключением указанного) могут быть использованы и по отношению к женщине (человек науки, искусства; человек большого ума; маленький человек; настоящий человек).

"Наше" обращение "молодой человек" используется исключительно по отношению к лицам мужского пола — по определению.
"Молодая человек" или "молодая человека" — ни один грамотный русский так никогда не скажет, если только не захочет обидеть девушку или пошутить.